# OP_RETURN in rawtransaction rejected with error code -25

Tags: raw-transaction, rpc-error-25

I'm newbie with bitcoin, i'm trying to generate a rawtransaction but bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction return me an error code -25.

The transaction is

```
{
  "locktime": 0, 
  "version": 1, 
  "vin": [
    {
      "sequence": 4294967295, 
      "scriptSig": {
        "hex": "48304502204912c3f006284a9d0b57ded3fc8f04f72e2a48000f28967e0069bda6a9d8bac6022100e7af707986ff5b52e5d5868726156eded2ef29ccda1a8ad83f98d71597dcdce3012102d7c641bc6e04d3717416356e1b42fb5c5be6780f8c819715789efc6dafdf0539", 
        "asm": "304502204912c3f006284a9d0b57ded3fc8f04f72e2a48000f28967e0069bda6a9d8bac6022100e7af707986ff5b52e5d5868726156eded2ef29ccda1a8ad83f98d71597dcdce301 02d7c641bc6e04d3717416356e1b42fb5c5be6780f8c819715789efc6dafdf0539"
      }, 
      "vout": 1, 
      "txid": "a713489612f927ccc3c410173a8d616d6f17df0774e3e79d7715b4cfc72ec6a4"
    }
  ], 
  "vout": [
    {
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "type": "nulldata", 
        "hex": "6a0a444b4559736563726574", 
        "asm": "OP_RETURN 444b4559736563726574"
      }, 
      "value": 0.0, 
      "n": 0
    }
  ], 
  "txid": "4481f82e7d6b298597d211881b107740bc0f2b2244e898261c42c38505a3efb8"
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no txid=a713489612f927ccc3c410173a8d616d6f17df0774e3e79d7715b4cfc72ec6a4 in blockchain. You are trying to spend non-existed output.

Comment: I run it on `regtest`, just simple do `listunspent 1` and it shows me many transactions. And I pick one of those and Could I do it like this?